# Upgrading terrform from 0.11.13 to 1.3.6

Tags: terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.11

We have terraform for our AWS infrastructure provisioning which uses a very old 0.11.13 version. We have a requirement to upgrade to the newer 1.3.6 version but are facing some challenges.

As per the terraform docs we cannot just upgrade to 1.3.6 from 0.11.13. We have to go from 0.11.13 to 0.12 and then to 0.13 and then to 0.14 and maybe after that we might be able to go to 1.3.6.

I tried looking up at different options and because we need to perform this upgrade on various test and prod environments, doing multiple upgrades everywhere is not an option.

Is there a way to do this without using the terraform upgrade tool ?

Also, we don't mind destroying the current terraform managed resources apart from SQS and SNS. How would one achieve this ? Anyone has any experience with a jump of versions like this ?

Comment: Use something like tfenv? https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv

Comment: Can you provide the doc that you are referring to ?
Also you can start from scratch and just import the current state of resources from the remote backend and deploy the resources again. (Suggesting this as you have mentioned that you can destroy current terraform managed resources, this gives me an assumption that your infra is not that much complex.)

Comment: @ShobitJain I did think about using the import. But then I don't want to manually import each and every resource that way. I have 10 launch configs and 10 ASGs associated with that along with all of their ELBs. I also have some SQS and SNS resources. Those are the only ones I cannot destroy. Is there an easy way to do a bulk import that you are aware of ?

Comment: @Paolo This looks like a useful tool to use on my local to test out things but unfortunately, i might not be able to use this in prod environments. Cheers though!

Comment: @daze-hash, try this and see if it works for you. It is built for bulk import only. 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer. Let me know if this works for you and I will comment it as answer.